# ARCore list of supported devices in the future

Tags: arcore

I hope there is no other topic with the same question but I couldn't find anything related.

Is there a list of supported future devices for ARCore and when those will be probably available? I just got a Huawei Mate10 pro and would love to know when it will be supported.

I'm also up for testing alpha/beta versions.

Comment: You should better explain the argument of your question, not just only using tags, but also on the question itself.

Comment: The answer is probably "No there isn't", and this isn't the place to ask ... since asking us to find external resources for you is off-topic.  And if you are expecting us (StackOverflow) to assemble such a list, that is unrealistic.  The only people who can make a prediction of when a device might be supported are the people who are / will be implementing that support.  They are not here.  Or if they are here, they are keeping quiet.  (As you would ... if your boss told you to do so!)

Comment: *"I'm also up for testing alpha/beta versions."*  - Reach out to people who you *think* might be developing support for some device.  (Again.  This is not an appropriate forum ...)

Answer (score 1):

The ARCore developer previews currently only work with Pixel (XL), Pixel 2 (XL) and Samsung Galaxy S8 devices.

You may want to follow this thread on ARCore's GitHub issues: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/89

In the meantime, if you want to get started developing for AR and you have an ARKit (iOS) compatible device, you can try [Viro React](https://viromedia.com/viroreact) which is a cross-platform AR/VR platform with a write once run everywhere type of a deal.

Answer (score 0):

None can read the future, but you can follow the official list of supported phones as it grows:
https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/

As of 11/march/2018:

- Google Pixel
- Asus Zenfone AR
- LG V30/V30+
- OnePlus 5
- Samsung Galaxy:   S7, S7 edge, S8, S8+, Galaxy 8